# regularity of Newtonian Potential

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

I saw in [SOLUTION OF POISSON’S EQUATION](https://math.temple.edu/~gutierre/math8141/solution.poisson.equation.pdf)

Let $\eta(t)$ be a smooth function such that $\eta(t)=0$ for $t \le 1, 0 \le \eta \le 1$ everywhere and  $\eta(t)=1$ for $t \ge 2$. For $n\ge 3, \Gamma(x) = \dfrac{1}{|x|^2} $ and consider the function 
$$ \Gamma_{\epsilon}(x) = \Gamma(x) \eta(|x|/ \epsilon),$$
where $\epsilon > 0$.

1. If $\rho\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ 
   $$ w_{\epsilon}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \rho(y) \Gamma_{\epsilon}(x-y)dy \rightarrow   w(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \rho(y) \Gamma(x-y)dy $$
   with the argument
   \begin{equation}
   w_\epsilon(x) - w(x) = \int_{|x-y| \le 2\epsilon} \rho(y) (1 - \eta(|x-y|/\epsilon))dy.
   \end{equation}

So
\begin{equation}
|w_\epsilon(x) - w(x)| \le \int_{|x-y| \le 2\epsilon} |\rho(y)| dy \le \|\rho\|_{\infty}\epsilon^n.
\end{equation} 
But I think
\begin{equation}
w_\epsilon(x) - w(x) = \int_{|x-y| \le 2\epsilon} \rho(y) \Gamma(|x-y|)(1 - \eta(|x-y|/\epsilon))dy.
\end{equation}
This is in the page 3. In the page 4 we have
2.\begin{equation}
C_n \|\rho\|_{\infty} \int_{|x-y|\le 2 \epsilon} \Bigl( \dfrac{1}{|x-y|^{n-1}} + \dfrac{1}{ \epsilon |x-y|^{n-2}} \Bigr)dy = C \|\rho\|_{\infty} \epsilon.
\end{equation}
But I guess
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{|x-y|\le 2 \epsilon} \Bigl( \dfrac{1}{|x-y|^{n-1}} + \dfrac{1}{ \epsilon |x-y|^{n-2}} \Bigr)dy &=& \int_{|y|\le2 \epsilon} ( \dfrac{1}{|y|^{n-1}} + \dfrac{1}{ \epsilon |y|^{n-2}} \Bigr)dy \\
&=& \sigma(S^{n-1}) \int_0^{2 \epsilon}( \dfrac{1}{|r|^{n-1}} + \dfrac{1}{ \epsilon |r|^{n-2}} \Bigr)dy\\
&=& \sigma(S^{n-1})[1/n \cdot 1/(2 \epsilon)^n + 1/(n-1) \cdot 1/(2 \epsilon)^{(n-1)}]
\end{eqnarray}
that tends to $\infty$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no question in your post, it's not clear what we are supposed to say. Apparently, you forgot that the switch to polar coordinates brings $r^{n-1}$ into the integral. This is why you mistakenly concluded that the last integral diverges.